# SharePoint Apps - App URL Prefix and domain settings in "Configure App Url"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin

We have an on-premise deployment for SharePoint 2013 - Enterprise.  We are in the process of setting up SharePoint App configurations.

On the "Configure App Urls" section,  we have specified to use the same domain where SharePoint is e.g. contoso.sharepoint.com and specified prefix as "apps"

We are able to download apps and add them onto the Sites,  but we are not able to browse to the apps.  clicking on the apps takes us to

apps-{appid}.contoso.sharepoint.com

Is there any other configuration required at our end?.  Are we supposed to have two different domains for Apps and SharePoint?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Yes you need to configure new domain for your apps and that can not be a sub domain to your sharepoint domain. Besides that you need to configure this new domain in DNS too.

Comment: Garima,  the Central admin page says that it is a recommendation to have a new DNS for apps,  however it is not a mandatory requirement for setting up Apps,  we can use a sub-domain of SharePoint domain.

Comment: Sudhir, please check this link
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx.
It gives detailed info on the topic. Hope that helps.